# Odoo11 Javascript Widget action not working: ClientWidget is not a function?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I'm still learning how to properly add your own **javascript** code. I'm trying to add my own stuff into Odoo backend. Anybody can help how we can create our own stuff in Odoo11.

I Use the following code but it does not work:-

```
In petstore/static/src/js/petstore.js:
odoo.define('tour_demo.tour', function(require) {
"use strict";

var Widget = require('web.Widget');
var core = require('web.core');
var Model = require('web.Model');


var ProductsWidget = Widget.extend({
    template: "ProductsWidget",

    init: function(parent, products, color) {
    this._super(parent);
    this.products = products;
    this.corelor = color;
    },
});

var HomePage = Widget.extend({

    start: function() {
        var products = new ProductsWidget(
            this, ["cpu", "mouse", "keyboard", "graphic card", 
                  "screen"], "#00FF00");
        products.appendTo(this.$el);
     },    
});
    core.action_registry.add('ProductsWidget', HomePage); 
});

In petstore/static/src/xml/petstore.xml:
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-name="ProductsWidget">
        <div>
            <t t-foreach="widget.products" t-as="product">
               <span class="oe_products_item"
                  t-attf-style="background-color: {{ widget.color 
                 }};">
                <t t-esc="product"/>
                </span>
              <br/>
            </t>
        </div>
    </t>
</templates>

In petsore/static/src/css/petstore.css:

.oe_products_item {
display: inline-block;
padding: 3px;
margin: 5px;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 3px;
}
-----------------------------------------------
In views/petstore.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_backend" name="give_name" 
           inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <link href="/petstore/static/src/css/petstore.css" 
            rel="stylesheet"></link>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/petstore/static/src/js/petstore.js">
            </script>            
        </xpath>
        </template>

        <record id="template_id" model="ir.actions.client">
            <field name="name">ProductsWidget</field>
            <field name="tag">ProductsWidget</field>
        </record>

        <menuitem id="home_page_menu" name="Home Page" action="template_id"/>  
    </data>
</odoo>
-----------------------------------------
__manifest__.py:

    'depends': ['base',],

    'data': [
      'views/views.xml',
    ],

    'qweb': ['static/src/xml/hellojs.xml'],
}
```

Anybody give the solution for this because i am new in odoo js and documentation is also outdated and new one is very advanced(unable to understand)...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using : var Model = require('web.Model');

Use : var Model = require('web.rpc');